# no route matches error on route in rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, rspec

I'm testing a RESTful api in rails using rspec.

My request looks like this:

```
before(:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    sign_in(@user)
end

it "returns a 200 code when a user checks a valid token" do
  get "/api/v1/users/#{@user.id}/token_check", token: @user.authentication_token
  expect(response.code).to eql(200)
end
```

when i run the testing suite, I receive the error:

```
Failure/Error: get "/api/v1/users/#{@user.id}/token_check", token: @user.authentication_token
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"/api/v1/users/1/token_check", :controller=>"api/v1/users", :token=>"6fgswkHwWXrcyDQNJVBZ"}
     # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/users_controller_spec.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

However, I can see the route for this action in rake routes:

```
 api_v1_user_token_check GET    /api/v1/users/:user_id/token_check(.:format) api/v1/users#token_check {:format=>:son}
```

I match this to my users_controller#token_check. Here is my controller and action:

```
def token_check
        render json: {
            result: ['Your authentication token is valid'],
        }, status: 200
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No route matches {:action=>"/api/v1/users/1/token_check", :controller=>"api/v1/users", :token=>"6fgswkHwWXrcyDQNJVBZ"}

As the error message shows, you just need to specify the action name.

from `get "/api/v1/users/#{@user.id}/token_check", token: @user.authentication_token`

to `get "token_check", user_id: @user.id, token: @user.authentication_token`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error. I solved this issue by simply moving it statement inside  `:type => :request` describe statement like below:

```
   describe 'GET /v1/feeds/' , :type => :request do
      get '/api/v1/cars/random',  xhr: true,  headers: { 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json', 'ACCEPT' => 'application/json'  } 
        expect(response.status).to eq 401
      end
    end
```